# Обработка событий ОС (Linux, X-server)

Tags: события, qt, c++, linux

Как обрабатывать сообщения операционной системы в одном приложении Qt?

Нужно поймать события клика на любом месте рабочеко стола\открытых окон и прочитать значения пикселя по координатам X, Y

Читал про `QApplication::processEvent`, но что конкретно с этим делать, не пойму, можно ли в Qt сделать так, не используя xlib?

Еще можно cat'ить `/dev/input/mouse0`, но там вообще темный лес.

Comment: требуется расшифровка — что понимается под «событиями ос».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin сообщения операционной системы в одном приложении QT (linux, X-server) чего непонятного? А вообше задачу я давно решил, через файл /dev/input/mouse0 опытный пользователь  Linux пйомет, что нужно парсить глобальнгые события мыши.

Comment: @OlegUP, если вопрос заново откроют, напишите пожалуйста ответ.

Comment: @Olter https://yadi.sk/d/cuZvOMpriN6QE да можно и не ждать, тут готовое решение. Qt 4.8

Comment: @OlegUP, оформите, пожалуйста, «готовое решение» в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Все делается через /dev/input/mice
Коды mousedown и mouserelease есть в [исходниках](http://yadi.sk/d/cuZvOMpriN6QE). Использовал Qt 4.8.5